# svn edit commandline usage to replace old external to new external

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN external defined as `^/project/subproj1/subproj2/subproj3/trunk@revision lib` which needs to be replaced with `^/project/subproj1/subproj2/subproj3/tags/tagname lib`

I have tried to use the below command which is not working.

```
svn propedit svn:externals --editor-cmd "(echo /project/subproj1/subproj2/subproj3/tags/tagname lib) >" 
http://myname.com/project/subproj1/subproj2/subproj3/tags/subproj3tag/system -m "Test tag"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first dump the `svn:externals` property to a text file:

```
svn propget svn:externals . > externals.txt
```

...then do the modification to the file with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/trunk@revision/tags\/tagname/' externals.txt
```

...and finally set the modified property again:

```
svn propset svn:externals . -F externals.txt
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you could even do it in a single command line:

```
svn pg svn:externals . | sed 's/trunk@revision/tags\/tagname/' | svn ps svn:externals . -F -
```

Comment: @VinodBeriki if it helped you, please upvote and accept my answer ;)